# Refactoring legacy infrastructure on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, refactoring

Can somebody please recommend some sources on how best to approach refactoring a legacy AWS infrastructure? That is, how to reduce downtime, optimally migrate data stores (such as DynamoDB or S3), etc. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/) is a better place to ask open questions like this. You are more likely to get a useful answer there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of approaches you can take to do this.

AWS have a lot of great resources on "migration", as an initial thought take a look at the [6 Strategies for Migrating Applications to the Cloud](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/enterprise-strategy/6-strategies-for-migrating-applications-to-the-cloud/). Whilst you're already in the AWS Cloud it is a great time to evaluate whether you have anything you can replace or is no longer needed.

There are a number of services that assist with migration, for migrating data stores take a look at the below 2 services which might help to migrate most of your data needs:

- [Database Migration Service](https://aws.amazon.com/dms/)
- [Data Pipeline](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/what-is-datapipeline.html)

Other services such as S3 you would need to migrate to another S3 bucket, as buckets are uniquely named. If you want to keep the name you will need to [delete the origin bucket first](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-bucket-migrate-region/). If it is being served publicly try using a [CloudFront](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/) distribution and then switching the origin to the new S3 bucket afterwards.

For architecting your new infrastructure take a look at the [AWS Well-Architected Framework](https://aws.amazon.com/architecture/well-architected/).

There are a number of [migration whitepapers](https://aws.amazon.com/whitepapers/?whitepapers-main.sort-by=item.additionalFields.sortDate&whitepapers-main.sort-order=desc&awsf.whitepapers-category=categories%23migration) that AWS has also produced, some are specific to particular technologies and some are more general.

Comment: Thank you, these seem to be very helpful!

Comment: No problem, have a great day :)